# check that at least 1 checkbox is checked using javascript rules and messages

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to display message that if no checkbox is checked .  I'm using javvascript rules and messages

```
 <form   method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data name="english_registration_form" id="english_registration_form" >
   <div class="col-sm-12  inputgrp2 mstatu">
      <label class="labelclass">Marital Status*</label>
      <div id="result"></div>
      <span id="chkMaritalStatus" class="multiChkBox" >
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="chkmstatus[]" value="Never Married  required">
            <label>Never Married</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <input   type="checkbox" name="chkmstatus[]" value="Awaiting Divorce" id="chkchild" required>
            <label >Awaiting Divorce</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="chkmstatus[]" value="Seperated"  id="chkchild2" required>
            <label >Seperated</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="chkmstatus[]" value="Widow/Widower"  id="chkchild3" required>
            <label>Widow/Widower</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="chkmstatus[]" value="Divorced"  id="chkchild4" required> 
            <label >Divorced</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="chkmstatus[]" value="Any" id="chkchild5" required>
            <label>Any</label>
         </div>
      </span>
   </div>
   <input type='submit' class='btn btn-finish btn-fill btn-success btn-wd' name='finish' value='Finish' />
</form>
```

And this is my js

```
var $validator = $('.wizard-card form').validate({
          rules: {
'chkmstatus[]': {required: true},
 /*chkmstatus: {
                  required: function(elem)
            {
                return $("input.select:checked").length > 0;
            }
            },*/
 },

 messages: {
chkmstatus[]: "You must check at least 1 box",
}
});
```

I was trying to keep it as simple as possible and found this example here on site point but it doesn't seem to work how i'm using it.

Comment: ok i got it ..thanks @Aswin Ramesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

- **Error:** you need wrap `chkmstatus[]` in single-quotes like `'chkmstatus[]'` inside `messages`.
- **Your solution:** add `min-length:1` as a rule of your `'chkmstatus[]'` inside `rules`.

**It would look like:**

```
var $validator = $('.wizard-card form').validate({
    rules: {
        'chkmstatus[]': {
            required: true,
            minlength: 1, // <-- Add this line
        },
    },
    messages: {
        // add single quotes
        'chkmstatus[]': "You must check at least 1 box",
    }
});
```

> [jQuery-validate-minlength-method](https://jqueryvalidation.org/minlength-method/)
>
> **Description:** Makes the element require a given minimum length.
>
> Works with text inputs, selects and **checkboxes**.
>   Return false if the element is
>
> - some kind of text input and its value is too short
> - a set of **checkboxes** that doesn't have enough boxes checked
> - a select and doesn't have enough options selected

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..!

```
$("#english_registration_form").submit(function(){
    var checked = $("#english_registration_form input:checked").length > 0;
    if (!checked){
        alert("Please check at least one checkbox");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Check out this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lj8mwa0o/

Hope this helps..!